# HTMLフォームのselect要素を必須項目にする

Tags: html, form

### 問題の要約

HTMLでフォームを作っています．

その中に次のような select要素があります．

```html
<form>
    <select name="hogehoge">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <p class='button'>
        <input type='submit' value='送信'>
    </p>
</form>
```

ユーザーは，クリックして１～３のうちから何かを選んで，送信します．

このときに，select 要素の内容を必須項目にするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

#### 試したこと

フォームに `required` を指定してみてもうまくいきません．select タイプのフォームは常に何かが選択された状態になっていますから，機能しません．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず selected にした option を用意し，そこに「選択してください」などの選択を促す文言を書きます．これで「選択してください」が選択された状態からスタートするようになります．

その option の value の値は空白にしておきます．これで，初期状態のまま送信しようとするとブラウザから「必須項目です」と警告されるようになります．

そのままだと「選択してください」が選択できてしまうので，disabled にします．

つまり，以下のように書きます．

```html
<form>
    <select name="hogehoge" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>選択してください</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <p class='button'>
        <input type='submit' value='送信'>
    </p>
</form>
```